# How to import CSS file if on a certain post type in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I was wondering if it is possible to import a css file if I am on a certain post type for wordpress. 
I use the @import a lot to keep my CSS organized with a CSS file that has all the CSS for each post type.

From what I learned it is best to have the least amount of calls pulling in other files like @import as possible and when I do speed test on my site that is always a recommendation to not use @important but I don't want to have one big CSS file I was wondering if I can do an if statement in my CSS that would only pull in the CSS file if I was on a certain post type. For example something like this

```
if ($post->post_type == "cards") {
   @import "css/cards.css";


}
```

Also if a method like this is possible would it even be worth doing for the site's performance/speed?

Comment: I think you will have to use jQuery for that.. I don't think its possible any other way

Answer (score 3):

Yeah you can load stylesheet on certain post type page. For that you will need to use `wp_head` hook to add you css file.

```
function add_my_custom_css(){
    if( is_singular('cards') ){
        wp_enqueue_style('something', 'the_url_of_your_css_file');
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_my_custom_css');
```

Here, i didn't used @import. Because wp_enqueue is the proper way to load/include a file for WordPress site ofcourse. And there's a plugin called 'WP Minify', this plugin grab all of your css file into one file dynamically, no matter if it is 1K CSS.